# Sage 50 Accounting - Creating Credit Notes

Tags: sage-erp

I am currently creating some **SalesJournal** and **PurchaseJournal** entries into Sage following the examples given in the SDK. This is more or less the same as what I do for Sage Line 50 as well, but I am stumped with one issue..

In Sage Line 50, we can the journal transaction type to be various different things, the ones I use are *SalesInvoice*, *SalesCredit*, *PurchaseInvoice* and *PurchaseCredit*.

In Sage 50 Accounting, I can see a transaction type for a Sales and Purchase Journal which has a setting for *Invoice*, *Order* and *Quote*... I cannot see one for credits!

I feel I am missing something obvious, but am unable to find out how I can create Sales Credits and Purchase Credits via the SDK, so can anyone point me in the right direction please? (I am using C# as my coding base by the way)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there's no such thing as Credits in Sage 50 Accounting. We would post these simply as negative invoices instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sagae has transaction types as follows:

```
sdoSI 1  Sales Invoice  
sdoSC 2  Sales Credit  
sdoSR 3  Sales Receipt  
sdoSA 4  Sales Receipt on Account  
sdoSD 5  Sales Discount  
sdoPI 6  Purchase Invoice  
sdoPC 7  Purchase Credit  
sdoPP 8  Purchase Payment  
sdoPA 9  Purchase Payment on Account  
sdoPD 10  Purchase Discount  
sdoBP 11  Bank Payment  
sdoBR 12  Bank Receipt  
sdoCP 13  Cash Payment  
sdoCR 14  Cash Receipt  
sdoJD 15  Journal Debit  
sdoJC 16  Journal Credit  
sdoVP 17  Visa Payment  
sdoVR 18  Visa Receipt  
sdoCC 19  Project Cost Credit   
sdoCD 20  Project Cost Debit - Charge  
sdoPAI 21  Project Adjustment In  
sdoPAO 22  Project Adjustment Out  
sdoCO 23 Project Committed Cost 
sdoSP 24 Sales Payment 
sdoPR 25 Purchase Receipt
```

The way i did this was to declare a trantype variable and pass it a value based on a dropdown in my app.